# Update newly created record on client after successfully processing the Create request on server

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

Please, consider following scenario:

- IgniteUI 16.1 igGrid powered with igGridUpdating feature and RESTDataSource
- User creates a new record through modal dialog
- Post request is initiated with form data
- Server processes the create request and returns an object, populated with correct ID
- In success handler on the client side, the newly added in the grid row has to be found and updated with correct ID returned from the server.
- The ID column serves as a grid's primary key and it's hidden

What happens when a new row is adding?

*We are watching infragistics.lob-16.1.js*

In `_dialogOpening()`, row 68167,  `_originalValues` are computed via `$.extend(this._originalValues, values, this._originalValues)`, where `values = _getDefaultValues()` or with other words `values.id = this._pkVal`. And `_pkVal` is a counter that is incremented each time when a new row appears.

Keeping that in mind, later, `_endEditDialog()` is called, where `newValues`, representing the entered data by the user, are merged with default values of the input form: `newValues = this._getNewValuesForRow(colElements)` followed by `newValues = $.extend({}, prevValues, newValues)` and `prevValues` are the same `_originalValues` from above.

Then an `_addRow()` is called, which calls on its run `grid.dataSource.addRow()` and a transaction is created.

My point here is the updating feature generates ID automatically for the new row and `ID = CurrentRowsCount + 1`.

So, if the grid contains 8 records, then newly created record will automatically be assigned with ID = 9. And imagine, if one of existing records has an ID = 9, then igGridUpdating's `updateRow(rowId, values)` will update both rows, existing and the new one. And I realy want to call this method in order to update the row with the data, returned from the server.

How could I intervene in the whole picture and accomplish the update of the new row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto-generated primary keys are only meant to cover the most basic scenarios. If your app supports row deletion you should change them with something that will keep them unique using the [`generatePrimaryKeyValue`](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.iggridupdating#events:generatePrimaryKeyValue) event.

Using updateRow after receiving the permanent keys from the server is the way to go, however, remember to pop the transaction from the [`allTransactions`](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.iggrid#methods:allTransactions) array so the update doesn't go to the server on the next `saveChanges` call.

Comment: It's working nicely! Such a shame, this event is documented since 13.2 and I have missed it... Thank you!